# Filter 2 fitting filters on "docker ps -qf name=foo"

Tags: docker

I have 2 docker containers running, named "foo:1" and "foobar:1"

I want to copy the ID of "foo:1" by using:

```
docker ps -qf name=foo:1
```

but the colon does not work being filtered.
Now how do I only get the output for "foo:1" with the docker ps command?

Comment: I'm not sure a colon is allowed in a container name.  Are these actually images?  How are you starting the containers?  You can use the container name in pretty much every `docker` command; why do you need to look up the container ID?

Comment: @DavidMaze I want to roll out an automated script which always collects the ID of the docker container with the name "Foo:1" but there's another container with the name "Foobar:1" which prevents me from going without the early colon.

Comment: `Invalid container name (foo:1), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed.`  Do you mean `foo:1` is the _image_ name?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, sorry. I solved it using the Containername now, which contains an underscore.